# Angularjs how to detect all content loaded finish in controller while there is few ajax call inside?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have checked several answer, but none is actually same as my scenario.

My purpose is to show a spinner dialog once the controller start, and inside the controller, there are few ajax to fetch data to feed into `ng-repeat` and other model.

I did in a stupid way:

```
$scope.global.loading = true;

$http.post('fetchData.do', '', config
        ).then(function successCallback(response) {     
            $scope.global.loading = false;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            $scope.global.loading = false;
        });
```

Obviously this is not a good way, all my ajax is asynchronous, and I only have one loading spinner `div`, meaning, it might have problem some time the spinner never disappear away. (sorry I was wrong, the problem should be disappear earlier before even there is other ajax still running)

I found some library to intercept angularjs `$http` call, but its concept is same as mine, so it doesn't work.

Any good way to start a spinner at the beginning of Angularjs controller and dismiss it after all the ajax finish? Or even better, all the `DOM` data (ng-repeat) is ready? The reason is, I don't want to let user simply click on some `DOM` that is not fully ready yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Don't reinvent the wheel.](https://chieffancypants.github.io/angular-loading-bar/)

```
npm/bower install angular-loading-bar --save
```

All your http requests will be intercepted and a loading bar will appear until each one is resolved.

The library doesn't propose an overlay (to prevent interacting with the page) but you can do it this way:

```
#loading-bar {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 99999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: all;
  cursor: wait;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do something like this?

```
$scope.global.loading = true;
var status = 0;

$http.post('fetchData.do', '', config
        ).then(function successCallback(response) {     
            status++
            if (status === NumOfAjaxRequests) {
              $scope.global.loading = false:
            }
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
            //handle errors
        });
```

Increment some variable each time an ajax requests finishes. And then remove the loader once all have finished.

Another and probably better solution would be using Angular's built in promise library Q, and the q.all method which executes a callback after all promises have resolved. A good example can be found here: [q.All Example resolving multiple promises](https://www.martin-brennan.com/using-q-all-to-resolve-multiple-promises/)