# How show overlay with loading gif while finish my http.post in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, angularjs-directive

friends i try this add div with ng-show(loading), when initialize my controller put false to loading and when user click to button :

`<button ng-click="AddUser(user)">Yes</button>`

```
$scope.AddUser = function(user) {

        user.approved = true;
        $scope.loading = true;

        $http.get('/group/' + user.group).success(function(resp) {
            $scope.error = "";
            user.name = resp.name;              
            user.company = resp.company;                

            $http.post('/approvedUser', user).success(function(response) {

                $scope.loading = false;
                $location.path('/admin/listUsers');                 

            }).error(function(response) {
                $scope.error = "There was a problem!";
            });


        }).error(function() {
            $scope.error = "Problem listing Groups";
        });     

};
```

I need add div overlay with loading animation while user is create,this proccess is litle slow because i call external API in post and i want that user can't use system to finilize the proccess.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39606384/angularjs-how-to-detect-all-content-loaded-finish-in-controller-while-there-is-f/39609221#39609221

Answer (score 0):

In your view define one dive and inside it one gif image should be there like this :

```
<div ng-if="status">
  <img src="link of gif image" />
</div>
```

and then initialize status variable from controller when page is load first time

```
 $scope.status = 0;
```

Then, one minor change in your AddUser function :

```
$scope.status= 0; // initialize loading image parent div

$scope.AddUser = function(user) {

        user.approved = true;
        $scope.loading = true;
        $scope.status= 1; // Show loading image
        $http.get('/group/' + user.group).success(function(resp) {
            $scope.error = "";
            user.name = resp.name;              
            user.company = resp.company;                

            $http.post('/approvedUser', user).success(function(response) {
                $scope.status= 0; // Hide loading image
                $scope.loading = false;
                $location.path('/admin/listUsers');                 

            }).error(function(response) {
              $scope.status= 0; // Hide loading image
                $scope.error = "There was a problem!";
            });


        }).error(function() {
            $scope.status= 0;// Hide loading image
            $scope.error = "Problem listing Groups";
        });     

};
```